# Write Text on Image ( Specified width )

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, drawstring

[image: current example]

I am generating ICards for employees.
I have to write address of the employee on the ICard.

```
            Image blankICard = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\admin\Pictures\filename.jpg");

            Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(blankICard.Width, blankICard.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            System.Drawing.SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 88, 89, 91));
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(blankICard, new Rectangle(0, 0, blankICard.Width, blankICard.Height),
                new Rectangle(new Point(), blankICard.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                Font stringFont = new Font("FreightSans Medium", 20, FontStyle.Regular);

                string address = "Address goes here";

                graphics.DrawString(address, new Font("FreightSans Medium", 20, FontStyle.Regular), b, new Point(621, 234));
                graphics.DrawString("Employee Code:12345678", new Font("FreightSans Medium", 26, FontStyle.Regular), b, new Point(350, 407));
            }
```

Current Output is shown in the left side of the image.
Here what happens that my string goes out of the box.

I want to bind it in the fix size box.

Example is shown in the right side of the Image.

Comment: use this overload of drawstring: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Graphics.DrawString` overload that takes `Rectangle` instead of a point. That way you'll wrap text to fit within specified width.

```
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage)){
  // Draw whatever you need first
  // ....
  // Create font...
  graphics.DrawString(employeeCode, font, Brushes.Black,
                       new Rectangle(0, 25, maxWidth, maxHeight);
}
```

Simple as that :)

Answer (score 3):

I made some changes to your code, commenting 2 lines - I did not have the file `C:\Users\admin\Pictures\filename.jpg` on my pc - That's why `blankICard` was disabled and so was its `Rectangle`:

You must set `maxWidth` in order to wrap your employee code,  for example.

```cs
//  Image blankICard = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\admin\Pictures\filename.jpg");
int width = 500;
int height = 500;
Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(width, height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 88, 89, 91));
SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
{
    graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(blackBrush), new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
    //  new Rectangle(new Point(), blankICard.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    Font stringFont = new Font("FreightSans Medium", 20, FontStyle.Regular);
    string address = "Address goes here";
    string employeeCode = "Employee Code:12345678";

    int maxWidth = 30;
    SizeF sf = graphics.MeasureString(employeeCode, new Font(new FontFamily("FreightSans Medium"), 26), maxWidth);

    graphics.DrawString(address, new Font("FreightSans Medium", 20, FontStyle.Regular), b, new Point(0, 0));
    graphics.DrawString(employeeCode, new Font(new FontFamily("FreightSans Medium"), 26), Brushes.Black,new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 25), sf),StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    //graphics.DrawString(, new Font("FreightSans Medium", 26, FontStyle.Regular), b, new Point(10, 20));
}
```

Comment: Width is working fine..but the rest of the data has been discarded , i want that data(rest of the data) should come in the down row.

Comment: Sorry , what kind of data are you talking about? In the example I set the maxWidth as 30, but if you increase probably you'll find the rest of the string. PS: I could not test with FreightSans for I did not have this font on my PC. I tested with ARIAL.